# How to structure a Research Project

Tags: research-process

I am starting with an independent research MSc thesis in Computer Science for six months.
I already have a research question, a goal to accomplish, and the dataset.

What tools can help structure, plan, measure and organize their research work?

e.g. Gantt Chart in Excel to overview the tasks;
keeping a daily journal of what I did, and a time tracking software.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE! Unfortunately, this question is a bit too broad for our community. Check around online; a quick google for "how do I begin doing research for a phd" pulled up [this](http://www.columbia.edu/~drd28/Thesis%20Research.pdf), which you may find useful. I also recommend you talk with your advisor and/or fellow students. Good luck!

Comment: hi, thanks for the feedack. I narrowed it down to the tools to use for good research project management.

Comment: You probably won't be surprised to learn that this is a common question. Start with [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83/good-practices-for-organizing-notes) which is pretty much the same thing, and also just do a [general search](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=organize+research+work) and peruse the answers. Happy to reopen if you have additional focused questions but I think you'll find some useful thoughts already written.