# Publishing a literature review

Tags: literature-search, literature-review

Over the course or the past year, I've become very familiar with a specific topic through a careful and systematic review of the background and state-of-the-art.

I think this could make for a nice publication, providing readers in similar fields with a handy resource and increasing my academic profile to boot.

However, I want to make sure that the lit review I performed is scientifically sound - so it must be transparent and replicable.

Do you know of any guidelines, best practices, or great examples to guide me as I get working?

Comment: What is your field?  I would think that practices could vary widely.  In your field, do literature reviews like this routinely get published on their own?

Comment: Human ecology. Yes, I've seen a few.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it is not specifically for general literature reviews, but more aimed at systematic reviews and meta-analysis, the [PRISMA Statement](http://www.prisma-statement.org/index.htm) is widely used in the biomedical literature, and even comes with checklists to make sure a manuscript has a few key elements, such as:

"Present full electronic search strategy for at least one database, including any limits used, such that it could be repeated."

Which is something that's pretty necessary for repeatability - you will often find for systematic reviews that an appendix is included with the actual queries used, what dates, etc. In a more general sense, that's what I'd look toward: "Does my review follow most of the guidelines for presenting a meta-analysis, even if it doesn't bother with summary estimates?" If you do that, you're likely on pretty solid ground.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to perform a limited search for **dedicated** *literature review (survey) papers*, either in your field (not sure, whether this should be preferred, as it IMHO might push you too far outside of your own "big picture" *view* of the field), or in any other field that you can digest.

In addition to the above, please check my recent and **relevant answer** to a similar question here on this site - along with some general advice, it contains some useful references on the topic: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/45290/12391.